# A way for c++ code to access records from the UniVerse database?

Tags: .net, c++, database, universe, multivalue-database

I know there is some kind of connection between .NET and UniVerse, by using UniObjects. But I believe that obligates use of .NET, and C# or VB.NET.

Also, I know by reading UniVerse manual that UniVerse can call C/C++ code from within UniVerse, but what I want is the other way around.

1. Can UniObjects be used for c++ project in .NET?
2. Can plain c++ (by plain i mean without using .NET platform) retrieve and store the data from and to UniVerse database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, although you have to hunt for it.

On the [U2 DevZone](https://u2devzone.rocketsoftware.com/) site Rocket Software has just launched, there is an article about **[writing a PDO Driver](https://u2devzone.rocketsoftware.com/accelerate/articles/u2-pdo-driver/u2-pdo-driver)** for PHP access. **This driver is written in C (iirc) and has all the source code supplied**. It uses the U2 InterCall to interact with the U2 system (UniVerse & UniData). You should be able to use this as a way of making calls to the UniRPC process (this is what UniObjects calls).

You have to sign up to the site to access the article & source code, but sign up is free.

Comment: Yes, you right, I can use InterCall and that PDO driver is a good example, even though is for PHP. Thanks

Comment: No problem, I'm glad the answer helped.

Answer (score 1):

There is a library called icsdk.  This will let you do just about anything that UniObj would let you do from a java or .NET framework but from C.  I don't have the manuals with me to check right now, but if you can get the documentation from Rocket, you want to look up the ICS, or Intercall sections.